# Calculate values of a column of one based on data from another file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am newbie in python programming but I think it is the best language to program the solution to my problem. I need to multiply the values of a column of data based on the column name. The column data will be multiply against a value in a file.

The files are as follows:

File A:

[image]

File B:

[image]

For any value that is a header in the column of file A (plastic, zoom, clutter, taxonomi, augment, reus, nois, inequ, event), look in the first column of file B. If found (for example, plastic was found at position [5: 0] in file B), multiply the referring value (ie, -0.00065165), ignoring the zeros. When the header value in the column of file A (plastic, zoom, clutter, taxonomi, augment, reus, nois, inequ, event) is not found in file B, ignore.

The output needs to be like this and save in a C file:

[image]

Comments: zoom, taxonomi and inequ have not changed because all values are 0. clutter, reus and nois were not changed because they were not found in file B.

Can someone help me? I was using pandas but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: What is the extension of file B?

Comment: can you please replace the picture and post text so we can look at the data

Answer (score 0):

You can read file B and create a dictionary. Then do a lookup based on column name and do the math. Here's how I did it. Once you have the final results, you can decide to use pandas csv file write option.

```
import pandas as pd
c = ['plastic','zoom','clutter',
     'taxonomi','augment','reus',
     'nois','inequ','event']

d = [[1,0,0,0,3,0,2,0,0],[0,0,2,0,0,4,0,0,1],[0,0,1.125,0,0,0,5,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,5,0,0,0,3,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,4,0,0,0,2,0,0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,columns=c)

b = {'say':-0.00065165,'event':0.21651611,'test':1.41651657,
     'augment':-0.98526511, 'plastic':-0.00065165,'zoom':-0.00065165,
     'taxonomi':-0.00065865, 'go':5.18909071,'make':-0.00633282,
     'get':0.000924913,'one':-0.00116829,'inequ':0.05518548}

for i in df.columns:
    if i in b: df[i] = df[i] * b[i]

df[df == -0.0] = 0
print (df)
```

The output of this will be as follows:

```
    plastic      zoom  clutter  taxonomi   augment  reus  nois  inequ     event
0 -0.000652  0.000000    0.000       0.0 -2.955795     0     2    0.0  0.000000
1  0.000000  0.000000    2.000       0.0  0.000000     4     0    0.0  0.216516
2  0.000000  0.000000    1.125       0.0  0.000000     0     5    0.0  0.000000
3  0.000000  0.000000    0.000       0.0  0.000000     0     0    0.0  0.000000
4  0.000000  0.000000    0.000       0.0  0.000000     0     0    0.0  0.000000
5  0.000000 -0.003258    0.000       0.0  0.000000     3     0    0.0  0.000000
6  0.000000  0.000000    0.000       0.0  0.000000     0     1    0.0  0.000000
7  0.000000  0.000000    4.000       0.0  0.000000     0     2    0.0  0.000000
```

Note that this output does not match your results for `zoom` and `augment` as the input in your `File A` does not match the output